# Range-V3: get base iterator

Tags: c++, c++14, range-v3

I try to use Range-V3 library (for MSVC), but due to lack of documentation I don't understand how to do one thing.

```
std::map<int, std::wstring> ss = { {1,L"1"}, {2,L"2"}, {3,L"3"} };
auto rng = ss | ranges::view::reverse | ranges::view::values;
auto it = ranges::find_if(rng, [](auto&&x) {return x == L"2"; });
if (it != rng.end()) {
    assert(it.base()->first == 2); // this does not compile
}
```

What do I get from `find_if`? Is this iterator? I want to get an iterator to base element, i.e. to value in `ss` map.

Here is the error I get:

```
1>d:\sources\ranges_test\ranges_test.cpp(11): error C2819: type 'ranges::v3::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>,ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=int,
1>            _Ty=std::wstring
1>        ]
1>d:\sources\fingrad\dev.fingrad\src\vc\lib\range\v3\utility\basic_iterator.hpp(656): note: see declaration of 'ranges::v3::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>,ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=int,
1>            _Ty=std::wstring
1>        ]
1>d:\sources\ranges_test\ranges_test.cpp(11): note: did you intend to use '.' instead?
1>d:\sources\ranges_test\ranges_test.cpp(11): error C2039: 'first': is not a member of 'ranges::v3::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>,ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=int,
1>            _Ty=std::wstring
1>        ]
1>d:\sources\fingrad\dev.fingrad\src\vc\lib\range\v3\utility\basic_iterator.hpp(656): note: see declaration of 'ranges::v3::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>,ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,ranges::v3::reverse_view<ranges::v3::sized_range<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>>>::adaptor<true>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=int,
1>            _Ty=std::wstring
1>        ]
```

Comment: What is the error you get? It probably contains information on the type of `it`. BTW your code compiles and runs fine with clang.

Comment: @Holt, I updated my question, but I can't understand it(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug<sup>1</sup> in [MSVC implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Range-V3-VS2015/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/basic_iterator.hpp) of range-V3 (or rather a missing feature). An easy workaround would be to replace your code with:

```
assert((*it.base()).first == 2);
```

This should work because [`operator*`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/basic_iterator.hpp#L426) is overload for `basic_iterator` while `operator->` was not.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you look at MSVC source for [`basic_iterator`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Range-V3-VS2015/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/basic_iterator.hpp), you will notice that there are no overload for `operator->`, while there is one in the original range-v3 [`basic_iterator`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/basic_iterator.hpp).

Comment: Sad, but the truth.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota It might be worth opening an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Range-V3-VS2015/issues) on Github. I don't have access to MSVC right now so cannot do it properly.